# How to properly test flux from sink (processor)?

Tags: testing, project-reactor

I have processor like class, which internally uses sink. I have made extremely simplified one to showcase my question:

```java
    import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;
    import reactor.test.StepVerifier;
    import java.time.Duration;

    public class TestBed {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            class StringProcessor {
                public final Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();

                public void httpPostWebhookController(String inputData) {
                    sink.emitNext(
                            inputData.toLowerCase() + " " + inputData.toUpperCase(),
                            (signalType, emitResult) -> {
                                System.out.println("error, signalType=" + signalType + "; emitResult=" + emitResult);
                                return false;
                            }
                    );
                }
            }

            final StringProcessor stringProcessor = new StringProcessor();
            final StepVerifier stepVerifier = StepVerifier.create(stringProcessor.sink.asFlux())
                    .expectSubscription()
                    .expectNext("asdf ASDF")
                    .expectNext("qw QW")
                    .thenCancel();

            stringProcessor.httpPostWebhookController("asdf");
            stringProcessor.httpPostWebhookController("Qw");

            stepVerifier.verify(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        }
    }
```

My stepVerified does not subscribe and when it subscribe (upon verify(Duration) call), it misses testing signals. I cannot move verify call before `httpPostWebhookController` method call, because, it is blocking and will fail because no signal comes.

How to use StepVerifier in such scenario?

Answer (score 3):

As I have asked on udemy course (instructor [Vinoth Selvaraj](https://www.vinsguru.com/vinoth-selvaraj/)), solution is to use `verifyLater` call. It will cause to trigger subscription and it does not block. Fixed test code:

```java
final StringProcessor stringProcessor = new StringProcessor();
final StepVerifier stepVerifier = StepVerifier.create(stringProcessor.sink.asFlux().log())
        .expectSubscription()
        .expectNext("asdf ASDF")
        .expectNext("qw QW")
        .thenCancel()
        .verifyLater();

stringProcessor.httpPostWebhookController("asdf");
stringProcessor.httpPostWebhookController("Qw");

stepVerifier.verify(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
```